# Python Deap library, how to access initRepeat mapping

Tags: python-3.x, mapping, built-in, deap

## What I want my algorithm to do

I want to have a bunch of random words as individuals in my population, whos fitness is compared to an "optimal" word. If the length of the words are equivalent, that's +1 in fitness. For each char that is the same, that's also +1 in fitness, +1.1 if it is in the same index.

Unfortunately I'm having a really though time understanding deaps docs. This is what I have tried among other things so far.

## Attempted Code

```
from deap import creator
from deap import tools
import random
import time
from create_random_string import get_random_word

ans = "hot"
creator.create("FitnessMax", base.Fitness, weights=(len(ans)+2,))
creator.create("Individual", str, fitness=creator.FitnessMax)

toolbox = base.Toolbox()
toolbox.register("individual",tools.initRepeat,creator.Individual,get_random_word, n=1)
toolbox.register("population", tools.initRepeat, list, toolbox.individual)

def evalOneMax(individual):
    fitness = 0
    if(len(ans)==len(individual)):
        fitness+=1
        for i in range(0,len(ans)):
            if(ans[i]==individual[i]):
                fitness+=1.1

    for i in range(0,len(ans)):
       if individual.find(ans[i]) != -1:
           fitness+=1

    return (fitness,)

#----------
# Operator registration
#----------
# register the goal / fitness function
toolbox.register("evaluate", evalOneMax)

# register the crossover operator
toolbox.register("mate", tools.cxTwoPoint)

# register a mutation operator with a probability to
# flip each attribute/gene of 0.05
toolbox.register("mutate", tools.mutFlipBit, indpb=0.05)

# operator for selecting individuals for breeding the next
# generation: each individual of the current generation
# is replaced by the 'fittest' (best) of three individuals
# drawn randomly from the current generation.
toolbox.register("select", tools.selTournament, tournsize=3)

#----------

if __name__== '__main__':
    random.seed(64)

    pop = toolbox.population(n=50)

    # CXPB  is the probability with which two individuals
    #       are crossed
    #
    # MUTPB is the probability for mutating an individual
    CXPB, MUTPB = 0.5, 0.2

    print("Start of evolution")
    fitnesses = list(map(toolbox.evaluate, pop))

    for ind, fit in zip(pop, fitnesses):
        ind.fitness.values = fit
```

## Explanation of Code(to the best of my understanding)

I first create a population that consists of my creator.Individual class mapped to a random word. I then pass this into my evaluation function to get each creator.Individual classes fitness. At this step I of course get an error because I'm not accessing the random word. My question is, how CAN I access this word?

## Alternative

I have tried an alternative method where I just keep the word as a variable in the Individual class like so, but this really does not play well with the rest of deaps functions that I am using. With this method I get errors in the crossover operator deap gives me. I would rather not have to create my own crossover operator.

```
creator.create("FitnessMax", base.Fitness, weights=(len(ans),))
creator.create("Individual", str, fitness=creator.FitnessMax, word=get_random_word(True,0))

toolbox = base.Toolbox()
toolbox.register("individual",creator.Individual)
toolbox.register("population", tools.initRepeat, list, toolbox.individual)
```

## EDIT

To be more specific, if I put a "print(individual)" line inside of my evalOneMax 
function it outputs

```
<generator object initRepeat.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x1076ffe60>
```

How can I access both the random word that is mapped as well as the fitness of the individual

Comment: With the answer to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51451815/python-deap-library-using-random-words-as-individuals/51451896#51451896 you should be able to get words as individuals. I mean no offense but did you walk through the tutorial in DEAP's doc? Your fitness declaration is wrong, you only have one value to optimize, thus the `weights` param should read `(1,)`.

Comment: Yes I have read over the docs multiple times. From what I understood, the **weights** param should read(max_fitness,) which is what I was doing, because my fitness function maximum changes depending on problem statement. 

Getting the words as individuals in the way done in the other problem forces the string to be the same word over and over.
 If you don't believe it, go back to other problem, create a population with

`pop = toolbox.population(n=50)` 

then copy my fitness function and put a `print(individual)` statement inside of it. It's the same word over and over

Comment: _The weights can also be used to vary the importance of each objective one against another. This means that the weights can be any real number and only the sign is used to determine if a maximization or minimization is done. An example of where the weights can be useful is in the crowding distance sort made in the NSGA-II selection algorithm._ 

This is the part of the docs that made me unsure as to whether the positive value of the weight was arbitrary. They say "any" number, but do not specify if 1 is the same as 5,

Comment: Ok so we had a different interpretation of the fitness' weights. It is true that if you only have one weight, the exact value does not matter much. My apologies for that. Concerning the individuals, I edited my answer to your other question again, hopefully this time, the reasoning is complete. This should allow you to move forward with your project.